# I am not able to pass the value from flask to react when I have assigned it to a variable

Tags: reactjs, flask

I am not able to pass the value from flask to react. When I check it on Postman then I am able to receive my desired output (that is my prediction) but I am not able to display it on my react frontend. It always takes the default value which is "test1".

I modified the code to test whether I can pass time.time() as the final output instead of prediction and I was able to display the time on react frontend. But when I assign my prediction_class variable then the default value is displayed.

This is my flask code

```
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from model.Train import train_model
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import numpy as np
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)

if not os.path.isfile('iris-model.model'):
    train_model()

model = joblib.load('iris-model.model')

@app.route('/predict')
def get_current_time():

    posted_data = request.get_json()
    sepal_length = posted_data['sepal_length']
    sepal_width = posted_data['sepal_width']        
    petal_length = posted_data['petal_length']
    petal_width = posted_data['petal_width']

    prediction = model.predict([[sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width]])[0]

    if prediction == 0:
        predicted_class = "Iris-setosa"
    elif prediction == 1:
        predicted_class = "Iris-versicolor"
    else:
        predicted_class = "Iris-virginica"
    return {'predict': predicted_class}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my react code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [displayType, predictedType] = useState("test1");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/predict').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      predictedType(data.predict);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      <p> The predicted type is {displayType}</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am new to flask and hope you guys can help me solve this silly problem.
Thanks

Comment: Hey Parth, You are using two applications here. right? A flask app and a react app. If so your `fetch(url)` url must be something like 'http://localhost:9500/predict''.

Comment: I have assigned a proxy variable as "http://localhost:5000" in my package.json file to avoid that.

Comment: If you return objects from flask `return {'predict': predicted_class}`, you should get the data as objects inside fetch. Just put a console.log and check what is the shape of the data. I think it should be look like `data[0].predict`.

Comment: I am receiving these two errors while I do console.log 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0' and 'GET http://localhost:3000/predict 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)'

Comment: Console.log error occurs because of the server error. Try this inside the useEffect `  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json));
  }, []);` . If you can see data from the console. Change the url and check your flask one too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but when I pasted that code I kept receiving these errors 'App.js:8 GET http://localhost:3000/jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts 404 (NOT FOUND)' and 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0' and no data in my console